# phpMyAdmin not using config file

Tags: linux, phpmyadmin

I recently updated phpMyAdmin version to `5.0.2`. After that I had some errors which I managed to fix, but one is still there. I get message:

> The configuration file now needs a secret passphrase (blowfish_secret).

I checked the `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` file and there was this part

```
// Load secret generated on postinst
if (check_file_access('/var/lib/phpmyadmin/blowfish_secret.inc.php')) {
    require('/var/lib/phpmyadmin/blowfish_secret.inc.php');
}
```

So I checked the `/var/lib/phpmyadmin/blowfish_secret.inc.php` file and edited it. It looks like that right now.

```
<?php
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'qVC[PK0l.GudqG/NR9jiq/hP,Go]CJ5H';
```

I made sure that all the files are in group `www-data` and have `chmod` at least `644`
I even added the line from `blowfish_secret.inc.php` to `config.inc.php` just to be sure it's there.

But the error is still there. So it looks like phpMyAdmin isn't using the `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` file for some reason. But I can't figure out why.

P.S I have two servers (one local VM, and the other web server). The local VM is Ubuntu 19.10 and the other is Debian 8. The problem is exactly the same on both, and I took the same steps.

Comment: How did you perform the upgrade? Are you using the packaged version or did you download the latest file from phpmyadmin.net and uncompress it yourself?

Comment: @IsaacBennetch The later. I downloaded and uncompressed. But earlier I did the same thing (for the previos version. I think it was 4.9.x) and it worked as charm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official distribution of phpMyAdmin (the file you downloaded from phpmyadmin.net) defaults to the configuration file in the main phpMyAdmin directory. Because of standards (usually [FHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) or some close variation), most Linux distributions require their packages to put configuration files in `/etc/` and the actual program files elsewhere. Odds are you either at one time had the packaged version on your system or followed a guide meant for the distribution's version.

You should edit/copy/modify the `config.inc.php` in your main phpMyAdmin directory where you uncompressed the download, rather than the files in `/etc/phpmyadmin/` which aren't used by your phpMyAdmin.

My guess is the reason for this error now instead of with version 4.9 is probably related to a security hardening decision to require a stronger blowfish secret phrase in more recent phpMyAdmin versions.

Comment: It worked! Thank you. In the end the solution was easy, duh :) And was googling all interent to find the solution

Answer (score 1):

I found for phpMyAdmin 5.2.1 that it is using BOTH files and locations - I changed the tmp variable in /etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php and that worked and got rid of error. But I found that the secret blowfish entry is not being read from /etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php but rather from core directory of /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/ (did not exist, I simply copied other config file from /etc and restarted httpd. Viola ! Now the secret blowfish error vanished. However, when I used openssl rand -base64 32 to generate the secret key, it was more than 32 bytes. So I had to manually count to fix the key and remove extra chars.
O/S: Centos7
Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/8.2.5
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 8.2.5
PHP extension: mysqli curl mbstring sodium
PHP version: 8.2.5
PhpMyAdmin: 5.2.1 (up to date)